# Please help. After I upload the products file,I got the error: Image file was not found

Tags: import, image, importexport

The image is in the folder /media/import/ ., please see the below 3 pictures.

[image: the error code 2]
[image: the file is there indeed]

Answer (score 4):

See the following issues

**Magento image size**

Images size should be less than 2 MB (since in most cases Magento does not upload bigger images).

**Spaces in image names**

Check if in image names there are no spaces, as sometimes spaces can be treated as additional symbols and because of this images may not be shown correctly.

**Images sort order**

Often small image/thumbnail image may not display when multiple images are loaded. In this case, it may help to set sort order of the image that should be shown as small / thumbnail to 0 or 1.

**Correct subfolders**

Check if your images were uploaded to correct subfolders at your FTP. For Magento import images process you need only image name in the file indicated. Then they should be uploaded to media/import folder. After images appending procedure, they will be placed to corresponding sub-directories created on the basis of image name, for example - the image name is “image123.jpg” and after import it will be placed to sub-folder i/m/image123.jpg (first sub-folder corresponds to 1st letter and second folder created on the basis of 2nd letter of image name). Check if your images physically uploaded to FTP and exist there.

**Media folder permissions**

Check if your media folder has all the permissions that allow you to do all the changes. In case there are some restrictions, most likely you won’t be able to upload images. There can also be some issues with the owner of the media folder - it occurs when you move Magento from another server. Check it out with your hosting.